# Error when updating function-based views to class-based views in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-3.5

I've been in the process of running through the tutorials on Django Rest Framework to build a simple todo list app.

When I transitioned from a function-based view to a class-based view, I started getting a stack trace to Django and all http calls started failing.

I'm using `virtualenv` to isolate dependencies, and using Python 3.5.2.

Anyone have any ideas about what's going on, or how to resolve this error?

I'm chalking this up to a configuration error or a version mismatch, but I'm not sure where to start.

/views.py:

```
from django.http import Http404
from list.models import List
from list.serializers import ListSerializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

class ListsView(APIView):
        """
        List all lists.
        """
        def get(self, request, format=None):
                lists = List.objects.all()
                serializer = ListSerializer(lists, many=True)
                return Response(serializer.data)

        ...
```

/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from list import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^lists/$', views.ListsView),
    url(r'^lists/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ListView),
    url(r'^lists/(?P<list>[0-9]+)/items/$', views.ListItemsView),
    url(r'^lists/(?P<list>[0-9]+)/items/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ListItemView),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Input:

```
curl http://localhost:8000/lists/
```

Trace:

```
Internal Server Error: /lists/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pwd>/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "<pwd>/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "<pwd>/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "<pwd>/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
[29/Aug/2016 00:03:32] "GET /lists/ HTTP/1.1" 500 61615
```

Env:

```
python 3.5.2
```

Requirements:

```
Django==1.10
django-lint==2.0.4
djangorestframework==3.4.6
logilab-astng==0.24.3
logilab-common==1.2.2
psycopg2==2.6.2
Pygments==2.1.3
pylint==0.28.0
six==1.10.0
```

Comment: It looks like you have some middleware defined in `MIDDLEWARE` that is not written as Django 1.10's new-style middleware. Please post your `MIDDLEWARE` setting.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev You were right. The issue was in `urls.py`. In this case, I neglected to invoke `as_view()` in the routing. Will update with the correct response and code.

Answer (score 0):

@SergeyGornostaev had the right intuition to look at and post `urls.py`.

In the refactor from function-based views to class-based views, I neglected to call `as_view()` on the views when I updated the routing.

Before: `url(<pattern>, views.ListsView)`

After: `url(<pattern>, views.ListView.as_view())`

This resolved the error.

---

Full /urls.py before:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from list import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^lists/$', views.ListsView),
    url(r'^lists/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ListView),
    url(r'^lists/(?P<list>[0-9]+)/items/$', views.ListItemsView),
    url(r'^lists/(?P<list>[0-9]+)/items/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ListItemView),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Full /urls.py after:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from list import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^lists/$', views.ListsView.as_view()),
    url(r'^lists/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ListView.as_view()),
    url(r'^lists/(?P<list>[0-9]+)/items/$', views.ListItemsView.as_view()),
    url(r'^lists/(?P<list>[0-9]+)/items/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.ListItemView.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```